# Trying to scrape information held in two spans of two classes of the same name

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to start of by saying, I am not good at any of this!

I'm trying to learn how to do scraping in Python and doing something for a personal project of mine.

This website right here(https://www.stilltasty.com/) contains rough durations of various food products before expiry. When inspecting the site I found that the rough duration of the food is held within what looks like an image.

You can see a snippet here, [both strings are in a span element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZH3n.png).

Doing this has allowed me to get access to the first duration held within the first arrow.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17130"

result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
print(doc.find('div',class_ = 'red-arrow').find_next('span'))
```

However, I would like to get two both and I haven't had much luck yet. I tried using find_all and looping over the results trying to filter by the span, but I get completely different results. Matter of fact I get two results, but it is the "Blue Arrow" img that I get as my output.

I will appreciate any help in this matter and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First collect all the elements wit class `red-arrow` and iterate the ResultSet to get your information from the `span`:

```
for e in doc.find_all('div',class_ = 'red-arrow'):
    print(e.find_next('span').get_text(strip=True))
```

As alternative you could use `css selectors` and chain your selectors:

```
for e in doc.select('div.red-arrow + span'):
    print(e.get_text(strip=True))
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17130"

result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

for e in doc.find_all('div',class_ = 'red-arrow'):
    print(e.find_next('span').get_text(strip=True))
```

#### Output

```
3-5 days
1-2 months
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @HedgeHog's answer, another way to do it is to use css selectors:

```
for duration in (doc.select('div.food-storage-right span')):
   print(duration.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
3-5 days
1-2 months
```